# Supremum of limit inferior

Tags: limits, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

Define the limit inferior of a sequence of sets as $$\liminf A_n = \bigcup_{N \geq 0} \bigcap_{n \geq N} A_n , $$ and the limit inferior of a sequence as $$\liminf X_n = \sup_{N \geq 0} \inf_{n \geq N} X_n, $$

Is it true that $ \sup (\liminf A_n) = \liminf( \sup A_n) $? If it is not, under what conditions is it?

Now for a secondary point, let $ L^\infty_t = (\Omega , \mathcal{F}_t, \mathbb{P}) $ be a probability space, and for each $t \in [0,T]$ we have a probability space ($\mathfrak{F}=  (\mathcal{F}_t)_t \small{\in[0,T]} $ is a filtration). How does the above question change if, instead of sup we use the essential supremum of a family of random variables random variables, i.e. for $X \in L^\infty_s, t \leq s, \text{ess} \sup_t X $ is the smaller $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable random variable that is greater than $X$.

Comment: What do you define as $\sup$ of a set ?

Comment: The least upper bound, a real number, of all elements of the set, i.e. let $\sup A = X$ then  $X \geq Y$ for all $Y \in A$ and if $Z \geq Y$ for all $Y \in A$ then $Z \geq X$.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a counterexample for the first part of the question.

$$A_n = \cases{ [0;2] & if $n$ is even \\ [0,1] \cup [3,4]& if $n$ is odd}$$
Then $$\liminf A_n = [0,1]$$ $$\sup (\liminf A_n)=1$$
on the other hand
$$\sup A_n = \cases{ 2 & if $n$ is even \\ 4& if $n$ is odd}$$
$$\liminf(\sup A_n) = 2$$
Remark: I suspect that with some effort one could show that
$$ \sup (\liminf A_n) \le \liminf (\sup A_n)$$
but the converse inequality is clearly false.